# Using varargs and callback in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I wonder how i could possibly fix this. I want to use a vararg for the loadid and i want to add a callback. As you know varargs should be the last in the list aswel as the callback.

See the code below:

```
void getEvents(@Path("id") long id, @Query("number") int number, @Query("age") int age, BaseCallback<List<Event>> cb, @Query("loadId") long... loadId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in this version. In version 2 the synchronous/asynchronous behavior won't be tied to the parameters defined in the method but rather a wrapping return type.

For now, use either an array or `List` instead (varargs are just a fancy way to construct an array)

```
void getEvents(
    @Path("id") long id,
    @Query("number") int number,
    @Query("age") int age,
    @Query("loadId") List<Long> loadId,
    BaseCallback<List<Event>> cb);
```

or

```
void getEvents(
    @Path("id") long id,
    @Query("number") int number,
    @Query("age") int age,
    @Query("loadId") long[] loadId,
    BaseCallback<List<Event>> cb);
```

Comment: Ok, true but i want something like this ....&loadId=23&loadId=24&loadId... and when using long[] or List<long> i do not get a repeat of &loadId=

Comment: Are you using v1.5.1?

Comment: No, seems i am using v1.1.1...i'll first update. Thanx